# code VHDL one shot timer

Tags: vhdl, fpga, test-bench

Now I'm coding VHDL to make a one-shot timer module. But I don't know which code is right in two kind of code, the first or second. i used the testbench i see the different. What the right code for monostable (one-shot) ?

**This is the first code:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity oneshot is
port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        ce : in STD_LOGIC;
        trigger : in STD_LOGIC;
        delay : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
        pulse : out STD_LOGIC :='0');
end oneshot;
architecture Behavioral of oneshot is
signal count: INTEGER range 0 to 255; -- count variable
begin
process (clk,delay,trigger)
begin
-- wait for trigger leading edge
if rising_edge(clk) then 
    if trigger = '1' then
        count <= to_integer(unsigned(delay));   
    end if;
    if count > 0 then
        pulse <= '1';
        count <= count - 1;
    else
        pulse <= '0';
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

[image: testbench imagine of the first code]

**This is second one:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity oneshot is
port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        ce : in STD_LOGIC;
        trigger : in STD_LOGIC:='0';
        delay : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
        pulse : out STD_LOGIC :='0');
end oneshot;
architecture Behavioral of oneshot is
signal count: INTEGER range 0 to 255; -- count variable
begin
process (clk,delay,trigger)
begin
-- wait for trigger leading edge
if trigger = '1' then
count <= to_integer(unsigned(delay));
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    if count > 0 then
        pulse <= '1';
        count <= count - 1;
    else
        pulse <= '0';
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

[image: testbench of the second one]

Comment: First. And only include `clk` in the sensitivity list. Also:`count` can be `unsigned`.

Comment: You edited first code looks much improved along with it's update waveform. (You could provide your testbench or count in the waveform(s). Note ce is not used.)  Ideally you might like pulse to go high on the rising edge of clock when trigger is '1'  and to go low on the rising edge of clock when count is 1 to eliminate the one clock delay - pulse is a flip flop.

Comment: thank @ JHBonarious  @user1155120 i use counter 10 clock cycles.

Comment: i use Black Box in Matlab/Simulink so it needs ce port.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions cannot be synthesized:

- The first has code outside the `rising_edge` condition.
- The second code has an asynchronous load condition.
  <s>That's not supported by FPGA.</s> That's not supported by all FPGA.

In general the second implementation is the closest to a solution. You can improve the down-counter by counting towards `-1` und using the `signed` type. -1 can be identified by the MSB being `'1'`. No need to compare n bits for all zero.

**Further issues:**

- The sensitivity list is wrong.

  - Signal `trigger` is missing
  - Signal `flag` is not read
- Library `unisim` is unused.
- Signal `flag` is unused.

Comment: So, what 's about pluse signal in testbench? It should ='1' when trigger ='1' or after trigger ='1'.

Comment: "You can improve the down-counter by counting towards -1" I consider this a micro-optimization. You'd at least need to increase the number of bit of `count` by one to ensure the positive range.

Comment: I just tried and the XIlinx tool allows asynchronous load. Just like an async reset but it also uses the 'set' pins alongside the 'clr'.

Comment: @Oldfart interesting ... changed my answer :).